# how install pear mime_type on wamp server

Tags: mime-types, pear

I can not install pear [mime_type](http://pear.php.net/package/mime_type) on wamp server for cmd windows :

```
$ pear install MIME_Type.
No releases available for package "pear.php.net/MIME_Type"
install failed
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you are behind a proxy and need to configure it -> http://blog.ekini.net/2008/03/06/using-pear-behind-a-proxy-server-that-requires-authentication/.

Another issue is that your package list is outdated -> run `pear clear-cache`

If that does not help, install the version directly:

```
$ pear install pear/mime_type-1.3.1
```

If that does not help, post the error message.

Then download the tgz yourself from the pear.php.net package and do:

```
$ pear install MIME_Type-1.3.1.tgz
```